# Determine the coefficients of the line

Tags: python, function, math

There are N points on the plane. Determine the coefficients of the line *y=kx+b* passing through the first and one of the remaining points so that all N points lie on the same side of this line, and perhaps on the line itself.

I need help with at least a mathematical description of the solution to the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explained by Michael Cao, you need to think in term of angles between the first and the other points. Assuming all the points have positive `x` and `y` coordinates, the point with the highest angle will also have the highest `tan` of the angle. This tangent can be calculated easily:

```py
def tangent(x1, y1, x2, y2):
   return (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
```

Hence, you just need to find the point with the highest tangent:

```py
def highest_point(points):
   x1, y1 = points[0] # coordinates of the first point
   maxi = (0, None)
   for x, y in points[1:]:
      if tangent(x1, y1, x, y) > maxi[0]:
         maxi = (tangent(x1, y1, x, y), (x, y))
   return maxi[1]
```

And finally, just compute the coefficients of the line passing through the first and highest points:

```py
def coefficients(points):
   x1, y1 = points[0]
   x2, y2 = highest_point(points)
   print("k =", (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)) # the coefficient is the tangent
   print("b =", y1 - (x1 * (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)))
```

(The last formula for `b` can be verified geometrically: the ordered at the origin is the ordered in `x1`, `y1`, minus "how much the slope went up from `0` to `x1`")

Comment: OK that's a good solution, but how it will work if the coordinates can be negative?

Comment: This would still work for negative coordinates, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the angle between your first point and every other point. Take the point that forms the lowest or the highest angle and use that point as the second point of your line.